# How to reference a video player URL in unity before the video is in the Assets folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have written a .exe that creates an mp4 from a series of images, then copies that mp4 into my Unity project Assets folder. It performs this when I click a button in the scene and it works properly. But since it takes a few seconds for the video to be created and put in the folder, I get an error saying cannot find file.

Here's what I've done so far as it pertains to playing the video if and when the mp4 is copied into the assets folder:

```
IEnumerator DoesFileExist()
    {
        string curFile = (some file path)
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(1);

        if (!File.Exists(curFile)) {
            yield return wait;

        }

        else
        {
            videoPlayer.url = curFile;

        }


    }


    IEnumerator PlayVideo()
    {

        videoPlayer.Prepare();
        WaitForSeconds waitForSeconds = new WaitForSeconds(1);

        if (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            yield return waitForSeconds;

        }
        rawImage.texture = videoPlayer.texture;
        videoPlayer.Play();

    }
```

Is there a way of referencing a video in the assets folder that hasnt been made yet?